# Бесконечное развертывание в NetBenas

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Столкнулся с проблемой при запуске проекта Spring MVC. После запуска бесконечное развертывание происходит. Доходит до следующих строк. Подскажите в чем причина? Сервер GlassFish

```
Loading application [TestProject] at [/TestProject]
Info:   Loading application TestProject done in 45 946 ms
Info:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  5.0  (25) startup time : Felix (46 010ms), startup services(49 400ms), total(95 410ms)
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.4.1 started in: 20ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
Info:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@48535004 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@4441d567.
Info:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://DESKTOP-STKODM1:8686/jndi/rmi://DESKTOP-STKODM1:8686/jmxrmi
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.4.1 started in: 221ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
```

Answer (score 0):

Переустановил NetBeans все ок теперь.